# Copy formula to next column

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I have a spreadsheet with ac column called **Cost** in the D column starting at **D6**. Then I have items going across containing the item names as well as their unit price where the unit price is always in **Row 4**.

What I need is D6 to equal (E6*E4)+(F6*F4)+(G6*G4) and so on without having to actually type the + next function over and over. Is that possible and if so what is the syntax for it.

I also need this formula to be able to work when I drag down the D column, so the next row is (E7*E4)+(F7*F4)+(G7*G4).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIPtw.jpg)

Comment: How far to the right does this formula go? If you really don't want to type the formula all the way out, then it's tough to imagine doing it with less keystrokes without using VBA. The second part of your question can be handled by surrounding the E4, F4, G4, etc. with $, like this: $E4, $F$4, $G$4, ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) function for this.

Something like `SUMPRODUCT(E6:Z6, E$4:Z$4)` should work.

Comment: Thanks Scott, fixed.